# Query Gerrit using REST API's?

Tags: gerrit

First I have some gerrit understanding in bit and pieces.

What I want is by using ***gerrit change url*** : -
***http://review.xx.yy.com/gerrit/#/c/240262/***

I want to get URL of the gerrit server and gerrit refspec (refs/changes/..) by using REST API's (using curl) or any other git commands.

Is it possible ?

Please comment/edit if question is not clear.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking about, but you can facilitate communicating with gerrit by using [git review](https://github.com/openstack-infra/git-review) tool. E.g. you can `git review -d 240262` to download the latest patchset of the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gerrit has a REST api that you can query.

To get [information about the Gerrit server](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/rest-api-config.html#get-info) you can use:

```
http://review.xx.yy.com/gerrit/config/server/info
```

You could use curl like this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://review.xx.yy/gerrit/config/server/info
```

If you want to [query change-sets](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes) you can use a form like this:

```
http://review.xx.yy.com/gerrit/changes/?q=owner:johndoe
```

Here is the documentation for Gerrit's REST API: https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/rest-api.html